# Encoding audio in realtime causes audible skipping

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

### **High Level:**

I use the same encoder in two different ways.

Way #1: record raw audio and save to an entire file, then compress file after it is all finished. **RESULT** Flawless audio

Way #2: record raw audio, encode it frame by frame. **RESULT** Audible skipping

**Why** does way #2 cause skipping?

### **Low Level**

Code for way #1 (writing to FileOutputStream fos, and compress after all writing is finished)

```
public void writeSample(short[] buf) throws IOException {
            byte[] byteArray = Util.toByteArray(buf,false);
            bytesWritten += byteArray.length;
            fos.write(byteArray);
        }
```

Code for way #2

```
public void writeSample(short[] buf) throws IOException {
            byte[] byteArray = Util.toByteArray(buf,false);
            bytesWritten += byteArray.length;
            encoder.encode(byteArray);
        }
```

ALMOST PERFECT:
The length of the short buf in way #2 is 15360.  Since this is an odd sized number, I employed this technique: but there is stil a slight audible skipping:

```
      ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
      byte[] readme = new byte[4096];
      int count = bais.read(readme);
      while ( count != -1 ) {
        System.out.println("READING :"+count+ " bytes");
        if(bais.available() < 4096) {
          System.out.println ("LESS THAN 4096 available: "+bais.available());
          byte[] remain = new byte[bais.available()];
          bais.read(remain);
          aacEncoder.encode(remain);
          break;
        }
        aacEncoder.encode(readme);
        count = bais.read(readme);
      }
```

Comment: Why does way #2 cause skipping. What logically could be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the deal: when the encoder encodes, it doesn't always take the same amount of time. Sometimes it just stashes some data away for later, and sometimes it actually does a whole lot of number crunching. It has to wait for enough audio to encode an entire MP3 "frame" or it will just stash data.

Every time there's a call for new data that requires number crunching, if it takes longer than the amount of time the audio represents, there's a risk that a dropout will occur.

The solution is to have your record thread fill a buffer and have second thread do all the work that might slow things down, or take an unpredictable amount of time. That includes encoding and writing to the file.

For your buffer, if you are targeting android 2.3 or later, you can use the piped [I](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html)/[O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html). This is not technically a ringbuffer because it blocks, but in my experience it works well enough. (This api is available in earlier versions of android, but you can't set the buffer size. Grrr!)

You might find this link helpful for understanding how the audio IO actually works conceptually: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2011/11/slides-from-fundamentals-of-audio.html

Comment: Maybe. However I challenge your hypothesis. When I record in AAC, the skipping occurs. But, when I record in OGG, no skipping occurs.

Comment: That's apples and oranges: different codecs, different algorithms, different CPU requirements and chunk sizes, all resulting in different timing requirements. Ultimately you shouldn't put anything with unknown timing requirements (including file writing, mutexes, and a bunch of other stuff) in the same thread as playback I/O. If it happens to work, it's because you are lucky and you got away with it, not because something is wrong with the other conditions.

Comment: Ive now implemented a produce/consumer threading model, and im still hearing clicking. So I really don't think its a threading issue.

Comment: IDK of any code samples -- I always do this kind of thing for work/closed source. It's a common question on the PortAudio Mailing list, so you might be able to find something searching there (although that's C).

Comment: Producer consumer in this case is trickier than it seems. You have to make sure your producer thread (the recorder) is never waiting to long for the consumer. Also make sure the buffer size is large enough. IIRC, you need a huge buffer size for MP3, something absurd like 5 seconds for really reliable playback/recording. You can also increase the latency/buffer size setting of the android AudioTrack, which will help.

Comment: It is only taking 10 ms to write to the BlockingArrayQueue in all 3 cases: OGG,AAC,WAV. The only format that skips is AAC. I have updated the question and set a bounty, however I will not accept your answer as my problem is not yet solved.